# How to get item value from ArrayList in an Object

Tags: android, xml, object, arraylist

I am trying to process XML plist data from an API, but am hitting lots of walls!

The data is Apple plist format, which I am parsing using Akos' code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904418/apple-plist-form-of-xml-can-i-parse-it-through-android-java) which seems to work perfectly. It is parsing as String, Object into a HashMap. I am able to get the value of a given key ie.

```
Object childItems = items.mPlistHashMap.get("childItems");
System.out.println(childItems.getClass());
System.out.println(childItems);
```

childItems.getClass() shows as - *class java.util.ArrayList*

The LogCat output for childItems shows -
**[{remoteFilePath=/Picture.png, host=www.host.com, ratingCount=1, targetId=82, commentCount=1, externalId=/demo.host.com/Private/Picture.png, fileSize=23738, entity_name=Item, memberAccessLevel=0, leaderAccessLevel=0, name=Picture.png, target=SystemUser, ownerAccessLevel=3, tagCount=1}, {lastName=Test, entity_name=User, username=Test, host=www.host.com, userId=82, firstName=Test, password=TestPwd, loginName=Test}, {typeId=0, entity_name=UserType, name=UserType_Teacher}]**

I presume that I can then work with this ArrayList, but this is where I am coming undone. For instance I want to get the remoteFilePath value, and display this in a ListView (already working for local files).

The example childItems list above only contain one file (Picture.png), but this list could contain any number of files, so I would need to iterate the list and get any values for remoteFilePath to display.

Any help appreciated, I just don't know how to "bore down" into this list, or if the childItems object needs to be cast to a new Array or so on.

If I'm missing any vital information, ask and I shall provide :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<?> childItems = (ArrayList<?>) elockeritems.mPlistHashMap.get("childItems");
```

I can now work with this. I need to get my head around the fundamentals!